# Number of elements in quotient ring of polynomials over a finite field

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

The following passage from Wikipedia's article on quotient rings gives an example of a quotient ring of polynomials over a finite field.

"One important instance of the previous example is the construction of the finite fields. Consider for instance the field $F_3 = Z/3Z$ with three elements. The polynomial $f(x) = x^2 + 1$ is irreducible over $F_3$ (since it has no root), and we can construct the quotient ring $F_3[x]/(f)$. This is a field with $3^2=9$ elements, denoted by $F_9$. The other finite fields can be constructed in a similar fashion."

I have two questions:
(1) Why must the resulting field have $3^2=9$ elements? 
(2) Why does $f(x)$ having no root imply that it's irreducible?

Comment: 1) It's a vector space over $\mathbb{F}_3$ of dimension $2$, spanned by $1$ and $x$. 2) It's quadratic, so if it were reducible it would have a root.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1) Because in that field, $x^2$ and $-1$ are the same thing. That means that any element has a unique representative with only first-degree and constant term (any higher degree term may be reduced). Each of those places has three possible values (being elements of $\Bbb F_3$), resulting in a total of $3\cdot 3 = 9$ possible elements. Here they are:
$$
\begin{array}{ccc}
0x + 0&0x + 1 & 0x+2\\
1x + 0&1x + 1 & 1x+2\\
2x + 0&2x + 1 & 2x+2
\end{array}
$$
(2) Because if it were reducible, then its factors would be linear. Linear polynomials over fields *always* have roots. The same argument works for third degree expressions, but not for degree four og higher (the prime example being $(x^2 + 1)^2$).

Answer (score 2):

*Fact 1:* Let $k$ be a field, and $f(x)\in k[x]$ be a polynomial of degree $n\geq 1$. Then for any $\overline{g(x)}\in k[x]/(f(x))$, there is a unique polynomial $g_0(x)\in k[x]$ of degree $\leq n-1$ such that $\overline{g(x)}=\overline{g_0(x)}.$

*Fact 2:* Let $k$ be a field and $f(x)\in k[x]$. If $f(\alpha)=0$ for some $\alpha \in k$, then $f(x)$ is reducible.

(To prove the above two facts, use division algorithm)

(1). In this case, using Fact 1, we see that any element $\overline{g(x)}\in \mathbb{F}_3[x]/(f(x))$ can be written uniquely as $\overline{g_0(x)}$ where $g_0(x)\in \mathbb{F}_3[x]$ is either a constant, or a polynomial of degree one. Since $|\mathbb{F}_3|=3,$ we see that $|\mathbb{F}_3[x]/(f(x))|=3\times 3=9$.

(2). If it has a root, then it is straight forward from Fact 2 that it is reducible. On the other hand, assume it is reducible. The $f(x)=p(x)q(x)$ for some $p(x), q(x) \in \mathbb{F}_3[x]$, and none of them are constants. So $p(x)=ax-\alpha, q(x)=bx-\beta$ for some $a,b,\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{F}_3$ and $a\neq 0, b\neq 0$. But then both $a^{-1}\alpha$ and $b^{-1}\beta$ are roots of $f(x)$.

Comment: What does the bar above $g(x)$ mean?

Comment: It is the image of $g(x) \in k[x]$ in $k[x]/(f(x))$ under the natural map $k[x] \to k[x]/(f(x))$.  $ \overline{g(x)}:= g(x) + (f(x))$.